# How to resolve an Unmet dependencies error?

Tags: apt, software-installation

```
$ sudo apt-get install -f
[sudo] password for sumit: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  linux-image-3.13.0-24-generic:i386
Suggested packages:
  fdutils:i386 linux-doc-3.13.0:i386 linux-source-3.13.0:i386 linux-tools:i386
  linux-headers-3.13.0-24-generic:i386
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  linux-image-3.13.0-32-generic linux-image-extra-3.13.0-32-generic
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  linux-image-3.13.0-24-generic:i386
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 2 to remove and 42 not upgraded.
9 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 14.6 MB of archives.
After this operation, 162 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Get:1 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main linux-image-3.13.0-24-generic i386 3.13.0-24.47 [14.6 MB]
Fetched 14.6 MB in 25s (580 kB/s)                                              
(Reading database ... 303483 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing linux-image-extra-3.13.0-32-generic (3.13.0-32.57) ...
Examining /etc/kernel/postrm.d .
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools 3.13.0-32-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-32-generic
update-initramfs: Deleting /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-32-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub 3.13.0-32-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-32-generic
/usr/sbin/grub-mkconfig: 1: /etc/default/grub: s: not found
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub exited with return code 127
Failed to process /etc/kernel/postrm.d at /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-extra-3.13.0-32-generic.postrm line 328.
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-extra-3.13.0-32-generic (--remove):
 subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 1
Removing linux-image-3.13.0-32-generic (3.13.0-32.57) ...
Examining /etc/kernel/postrm.d .
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools 3.13.0-32-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-32-generic
update-initramfs: Deleting /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-32-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub 3.13.0-32-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-32-generic
/usr/sbin/grub-mkconfig: 1: /etc/default/grub: s: not found
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub exited with return code 127
Failed to process /etc/kernel/postrm.d at /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-3.13.0-32-generic.postrm line 328.
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-3.13.0-32-generic (--remove):
 subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-extra-3.13.0-32-generic
 linux-image-3.13.0-32-generic
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)


$ cat /etc/default/grub
s
# If you change this file, run 'update-grub' afterwards to update
# /boot/grub/grub.cfg.
# For full documentation of the options in this file, see:
#   info -f grub -n 'Simple configuration'

GRUB_DEFAULT=0
#GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
GRUB_TIMEOUT=2
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

# Uncomment to enable BadRAM filtering, modify to suit your needs
# This works with Linux (no patch required) and with any kernel that obtains
# the memory map information from GRUB (GNU Mach, kernel of FreeBSD ...)
#GRUB_BADRAM="0x01234567,0xfefefefe,0x89abcdef,0xefefefef"

# Uncomment to disable graphical terminal (grub-pc only)
#GRUB_TERMINAL=console

# The resolution used on graphical terminal
# note that you can use only modes which your graphic card supports via VBE
# you can see them in real GRUB with the command `vbeinfo'
#GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480

# Uncomment if you don't want GRUB to pass "root=UUID=xxx" parameter to Linux
#GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID=true

# Uncomment to disable generation of recovery mode menu entries
#GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"

# Uncomment to get a beep at grub start
#GRUB_INIT_TUNE="480 440 1"
```

Comment: Can you still run sudo apt-get update ?

Comment: Some thing else to consider, run- uname -r -and find what kernal version you are on is it this one ?  3.13.0-32-generic

Comment: yeah i can run  sudo apt-get update

Comment: sumit@sumit-Ubuntu:~$ uname -r
3.13.0-46-generic

Comment: Can you remove it like this sudo apt-get purge linux-image-3.13.0-32-generic

Comment: am getting this:    
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 linux-image-extra-3.13.0-24-generic:i386 : Depends: linux-image-3.13.0-24-generic:i386 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).

Comment: You get this when you try to purge the kernel ?

Comment: Yeah i have run the same command as you have asked to and thats the output

Comment: pls give the output of `cat /etc/default/grub`

Comment: As ron said run cat /etc/default/grub in a terminal and add the output to your question

Comment: Please post also the output of `/etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub`

Comment: @kos -    grub-mkconfig: You must run this as root

Comment: @Ron- updated the the qns with the outhput of    cat /etc/default/grub

Comment: remove the `s` from the first line of `etc/default/grub`

Comment: Sorry, I meant *the content* of `/etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub`. Anyway the problem is in `/etc/default/grub`, see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After correcting your `/etc/default/grub`, run this:

```
sudo dpkg --purge linux-image-3.13.0-32-generic
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get -f install
```

Comment: done all three...

Comment: what's the error now?

Comment: no error...showing: done

Answer (score 0):

You have an excessive `s` line at the start of `/etc/default/grub`: run `sudo gedit /etc/default/grub` and remove the first line; save, exit, run `sudo update-grub` and try again.

Comment: yeah done all the steps..

Comment: @Sumit Have you tried `sudo apt-get install -f` again?